# How to list package names of multiple apks?

Tags: java, android, batch-file, apk

a `.bat` code to list package_names of multiple `.apk` files in a folder, into a `.txt` file with this structure:

```
com.a.a

com.b.b
```

Just by sending the folder path to my bat file. for example `b.bat "C:\apks"` which contains some `.apk` files, must create a `.txt` file and write all package_names of all files.

I tried to find a way, but wasn't able for windows, and for multiple apk files.

so how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the package name with `aapt.exe`. For example:

```
aapt dump badging path\to\file.apk | findstr /C:"package: name"
```

To iterate over files, you can use `FOR` (in command prompt itself, otherwise double percent sign):

```
for %i in (C:\apks\*.apk) do @echo %i
```

So combined, your batch file should look like:

```
@for %%i in (C:\apks\*.apk) do @aapt dump badging "%%i" | findstr /C:"package: name"
```

To write this to a file:

```
my_batch_file_that_calls_aapt.bat > my_text_file.txt
```

Or a bit more generic:

```
@echo off
SET FOLDER=%1
SET OUTPUT=%2
break>%OUTPUT%
for %%i in (%FOLDER%\*.apk) do aapt dump badging "%%i" | findstr /C:"package: name" >> %OUTPUT%
```

Make sure `aapt.exe` is in your `PATH` before trying any of these.

---

And just for a full picture, this is how you do it on Linux/MacOS X:

```
ls /path/to/my/apks/*.apk | xargs -L 1 aapt dump badging | grep package:\ name
```

Comment: and what about app's label?

Comment: Replace `package:\ name` with `label`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to [download aapt](https://dl.androidaapt.com/aapt-windows.zip), and add it to path.
Next, you need to open cmd in that folder.
Then, you could run this command to list all the package names:

```
for /f "delims=" %i in ('dir /b /on *.apk') do for /f "tokens=2 delims=: " %j in ('aapt dump badging "%i" ^| findstr /r /c:"^package: name="') do echo %j >> output.txt
```

If you want to list the filenames and package names in one file, use this command:

```
for /f "delims=" %i in ('dir /b /on *.apk') do for /f "tokens=2 delims=: " %j in ('aapt dump badging "%i" ^| findstr /r /c:"^package: name="') do echo %~ni %j >> output.txt
```